# SQL query to determine which users are online

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get a list of players who are logged into an online game (DayZ). The backend database is MySQL and the way to determine if a user is logged in is not exectly straight forward. Is is building this query that I could use help with.

Basically there is a table named `player_login` that makes a new entry everytime a player logs into and out of the system. If the user logs in then a field named `action` is set to `2`. If the user logs out the `action` field is set to `0`. Here is some smaple data (simplified)

```
LoginID     PlayerUID   DateStamp               Action
126781      79067462    2013-08-01 13:16:28     0
126777      79067462    2013-08-01 12:59:22     2
126775      79067462    2013-08-01 12:42:10     0
126774      79067462    2013-08-01 12:41:34     2
126773      79067462    2013-08-01 12:38:38     0
```

I can query the table to find out if a single user is logged in via the following query ..

```
SELECT PlayerUID, Action
FROM player_login 
WHERE PlayerUID = 79067462 
ORDER BY Datestamp DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

If the result is `0` then the last thing the player did was login and is therefore online. If the value is `2` then the last thing the player did was logout and are therefor offline. What I am having some difficulty doing is transforming this query into something that would return a list of PlayerUIDs where the latest `Action` value is `0` and thereby giving me all players currently online.

Comment: That's a little needlessly presumptuous.

Comment: @DanJ arent you curious?

Comment: Just by curiosity, how do you handle users that "log-in" but never explicitly "log-out" -- say because of a lost connection?

Comment: That is a good question. I am not really sure how the system handles disconnection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following query yields the most recent logout time for each player:

```
SELECT PlayerUID, MAX(DateStamp) AS MostRecentLogout
FROM player_login
WHERE Action = 0
GROUP BY PlayerUID
```

A similar query with `Action = 2` yields all most-recent login times. Combining these lets you compare them:

```
SELECT plin.PlayerUID, plin.MostRecentLogin, plout.MostRecentLogout, 
       CASE WHEN plout.MostRecentLogout IS NULL 
              OR plout.MostRecentLogout < plin.MostRecentLogin 
            THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 
       END AS IsPlayerLoggedIn
FROM (SELECT PlayerUID, MAX(DateStamp) AS MostRecentLogin
      FROM player_login
      WHERE Action = 2
      GROUP BY PlayerUID) plin
LEFT JOIN (SELECT PlayerUID, MAX(DateStamp) AS MostRecentLogout
           FROM player_login
           WHERE Action = 0
           GROUP BY PlayerUID) plout ON plout.PlayerUID = plin.PlayerUID
```

Note the LEFT JOIN and attendant NULL handling in the CASE statement: this is meant to handle players that have logged in for the first time and never yet logged out.

Comment: Thank you very much. Well explained also. I just added the following where statement (gleened from your code) that limits the results to only those logged in .. `WHERE (plout.MostRecentLogout IS NULL OR plout.MostRecentLogout < plin.MostRecentLogin) AND (plin.MostRecentLogin > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   SELECT PlayerUID, Action
   FROM player_login 
   WHERE `Action` = 0
   GROUP BY PlayerUID
   ORDER BY Datestamp DESC
```

Comment: This shows when each user last logged in, not whether they are currently logged in.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to sort by distinct player Id's otherwise you will get all times the player has logged in or out:

```
SELECT DISTINCT PlayerUID, Action
FROM player_login
WHERE 'Action' = 0
ORDER BY Datestamp DESC
```

Comment: This shows all players that have ever logged into the system, not those currently logged in.